# why the output file more than one byte via executing 'curl -r'

Tags: linux, curl

my english is poor！ :)

i want to download a 2G file with `curl -r` partly.

```
curl -r 0-1234567       -o file.part1 http://xxx
curl -r 1234567-2469134 -o file.part2 http://xxx
```

then i got:

```
file.part1 : 1234567 bytes
file.part2 : 1234568 bytes
```

file.part2 more than one byte, so i try to truncate the first byte:

```
tail +2c file.part2 > file.part2.truncated
```

then:

```
cat file.part1 file.part2.truncated > myfile
```

myfile is what i want.

Comment: And what is happening? Why are you truncating file2? You don't need the whole file?

Comment: @Sudipta Chatterjee . i make a mistake, and it works via truncating it, so i do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte ranges are inclusive, so it should be:

```
curl -r 0-1234567       -o file.part1 http://xxx
curl -r 1234568-2469134 -o file.part2 http://xxx
cat file.part1 file.part2 > myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--range` flag for `curl` includes the entire range, so you are getting the '1234567'th byte twice.

Additionally, because it is a 0 based index the end of the range should be less by 1. That is, they should be 1234566 and 2469133, because the range 0-1234566 is 1234567 numbers and so is 1234567-2469133.

```
curl -r 0-1234566       -o file.part1 http://xxx
curl -r 1234567-2469133 -o file.part2 http://xxx
cat file.part1 file.part2 > myfile
```